# Volume issues after reformatting on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, vlc-media-player, volume-mixer

I just reformated my HD on Windows 7 & we downloaded the audio drivers (RealTek).

The volume is too low on VLC even though this wasn't an issue before. I perfer only VLC, not MS software.

I usually had my computer volume at around 20-23% and that was fine with the odd video needing more volume.

This is my motherboard - [Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. 970A-DS3P](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-970A-DS3P-rev-10#ov)

We tried to tweak the settings in the sound device area and nothing really helped.

I sort of got it to an okay level, but then today when listening to a video on VLC, again it was too low.

Then I did something I normally never do and used the volume on my headset. This caused me to almost lose my hearing because when I got incoming mail in Thunderbird it was way too loud.

I don't know why I'm having so many audio issues.

Ok, so we did some more troubleshooting:

1. We jacked up the volume equalizer in VLC to the max & then min. The volume didn't change on 2-3 videos & on a 3rd one it changed only marginally.
2. We opened one video in Windows Media player Classic & that didn't change the volume (same issue.)
3. When I watch videos embedded on a website or on Odysee, the volume is fine.
4. We tested various different videos & the odd video sounds fine, but most of them weren't sounding normal at the normal volume my computer was at before I reformatted.

The only time I've ever had to raise the volume on my computer is when I do video editing, & then I raise it to 50% to test the audio in my own videos, so something is still wrong.

5. I had raised the volume on my headset several times now, so I don't even know what volume it's at or how to get it back to the mid range for testing. It's a Plantronics Blackwire C720-M Wired Headset.

Thanks

Comment: Reformatting and reinstalling may not update drivers (especially in long out of support systems). Get the manufacturer's driver update App and update all drivers.

Comment: We already installed the audio drivers. Thanks

Comment: I added more details in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Download and reinstall the Realtek HD Audio Driver for your motherboard.

If that doesn't work, make sure to check the Volume Mixer.  If VLC is set lower than main volume it could be proportionally quieter than your main volume meaning that other system sounds would be very loud.  Make sure VLC is at the same volume level as your speakers and then test again.

[image]

Another possibility is VLC has the Equalizer enabled - https://forums.tomsguide.com/faq/audio-output-in-vlc-player-is-very-low.341089/

Alternatively, try another media player to see if it's specific to VLC.  Media Player Classic is an excellent free alternative to VLC and is included in the frequently updated [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_standard.htm)

Comment: The audio driver was re-installed when we set everything back up.

Nothing in VLC in those settings helped at all. I chose the preset of bass & treble. 

I'm not sure that VLC's settings had ever been edited before, but I had someone else help me with the reformating back in 2018, so I'm not sure if he did something to VLC. I don't think so.

Thanks

Comment: I added more details in my question.